# Set expires for all virtual hosts nginx

Tags: nginx, cache

Is it possible to set `expires` for all virtual hosts (`server`s) in nginx while still filtering the filetypes?

Right now I'm using

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg|woff|otf|ttf) {
    expires 1y;
}
```

but I can only put `location` within a `server` and not `http`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a `location` in an `http` block, of course.

What you *can* do is to put this code in a separate file and then `include` it from each `server` block that you want to apply it to.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. It adds a bit of code to every `server` block though, but I guess it's the best way.